# Where to put downloaded java package?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I downloaded a javax speech class. I cant seem to import it in eclipse. It doesnt recognize it as an import. I think it is becasue i havent put the package in the right place. Where should i put it?

Comment: In your src (Source) folder? Is it compiled or a source file?

Answer (score 1):

add the class/jar in your classpath

right click on your project --> java build path
[image]